# Symfony Expression Language Lambda/arrow/anonymous function

Tags: php, symfony

I have complex question/answer system with questions that depends on answers on other questions' answers.

I'm using Symfony Expression Language to determine if question must be shown or not.

It works great, until it meets the array of Answers and I need to determine if array contains at least one element with some Condition. The problem is that array could be array of int/string or objects.

Basically I need lambda/anonymous/arrow functions like in Twig, but they don't seems supported in Expression Language. Any ideas how to solve that?

This is sample unit test:

```php
public function testContainsWithObjects()
{
    $item1 = new \stdClass();
    $item1->property = 10;

    $item2 = new \stdClass();
    $item2->property = 20;

    $item3 = new \stdClass();
    $item3->property = 25;

    $bool = $this->evaluate(
        'contains(array, (item) => item.property >= 25)',
        [
            'array' => [$item1, $item2, $item3],
        ]
    );
    $this->assertTrue($bool);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the input and desired results?

Comment: @El_Vanja Sure. I edited the question and added sample unit test.

Comment: Here's a useful chapter about [registering your own functions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/extending.html) to use in the expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar by registering your own functions. It's a bit more verbose than what you were aiming for, but ultimately gets the job done. According to the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/extending.html#registering-functions), what you need for registration is:

> To register a function, use register(). This method has 3 arguments:
>
> - name - The name of the function in an expression;
> - compiler - A function executed when compiling an expression using the function;
> - evaluator - A function executed when the expression is evaluated.

```php
$expressionLanguage = new ExpressionLanguage();
$expressionLanguage->register(
    'contains',
    function ($array, $callback) {
        // Haven't fully figured out the requirements
        // for compilation so I left it blank.
        // This example doesn't use it anyway.
    },
    function ($arguments, $array, $callback) {
        return count(array_filter($array, $callback)) > 0;
    }
);
$item1 = new \stdClass();
$item1->property = 10;

$item2 = new \stdClass();
$item2->property = 20;

$item3 = new \stdClass();
$item3->property = 25;

$bool = $expressionLanguage->evaluate(
    'contains(array, callback)',
    [
        'array' => [$item1, $item2, $item3],
        'callback' => function ($item) {
            return $item->property >= 25;
        },
    ]
);

dump($bool);
```

Dumping `$bool` results in true. You can expand on your callback logic to check the type of the argument and act accordingly, you can add more arguments to the `contains` function, register additional ones...

Comment: callback needs to be defined in/with expression, not externally.
That's why I gave the example expression: `contains(array, (item) => item.property >= 25)`

My problem is the part `(item) => item.property >= 25`